# porque mi ciclo de categorización en no funciona rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

necesito ayuda, soy nueva usando bucles en r y estoy intentando hacer categorizaciones para grupos de datos de un dataframe

```
cosecha_quinto_mes_1 <- cosecha_quinto_mes[cosecha_quinto_mes$month_count != 1, ]
cosecha_quinto_mes_1$categoria <- NA

# Crear columna "categoria" inicialmente vacía en cosecha_quinto_mes
cosecha_quinto_mes_1$categoria <- NA

# Obtener la lista de combinaciones únicas de site y year_class en cosecha_quinto_mes
combinaciones <- unique(cosecha_quinto_mes_1[, c("site", "year_class")])

# Iterar sobre cada combinación de site y year_class
for (i in 1:nrow(combinaciones)) {
  site <- combinaciones[i, "site"]
  year_class <- combinaciones[i, "year_class"]
  
  # Filtrar los datos correspondientes a la combinación de site y year_class actual en cosecha_quinto_mes
  datos_filtrados <- cosecha_quinto_mes_1[cosecha_quinto_mes_1$site == site & cosecha_quinto_mes_1$year_class == year_class, ]
  
  # Verificar si month_count es mayor a 1
  if (any(datos_filtrados$month_count > 1)) {
    # Obtener las diferencias absolutas únicas para la combinación actual (excepto month_count = 1)
    diferencias <- unique(datos_filtrados$diferencia_absoluta[datos_filtrados$month_count > 1])
    
    # Verificar si todas las diferencias son mayores a 0.4
  if (any(diferencias > 10)) {
      cosecha_quinto_mes_1$categoria[cosecha_quinto_mes_1$site == site & cosecha_quinto_mes_1$year_class == year_class] <- "con"
    } else {
      cosecha_quinto_mes_1$categoria[cosecha_quinto_mes_1$site == site & cosecha_quinto_mes_1$year_class == year_class] <- "sin"
    }
  }
}


cosecha_quinto_mes_1
```

Lo que intento con esto es que para cada `site` de cada `yearclass`, recorra los valores correspondientes de la columna `diferencia_absoluta` y si hay algún valor de todos los pertenecientes a esa combinacion mayor a 0.4 se le clasifique como "con" y si es menor igual sea "sin" sin embargo no logro que eso suceda porque me categoriza todos como con o sin, sin respetar la condicion, es como si no lo viera a nivel de site-year_class.

Espero me puedan ayudar

Comment: ¡Hola @Evelyn! Para poder comprender mejor el problema sería recomendable tener un ejemplo de los datos con los que trabajas (bien sean esos o inventados con la misma estructura). Puedes utilizar lo que devuelve la función `dput(cosecha_quinto_mes_1)` para generarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Voy a limitarme a la explicación que has dado:

> para cada site de cada yearclass, recorra los valores correspondientes
> de la columna diferencia_absoluta y si hay algún valor de todos los
> pertenecientes a esa combinacion mayor a 0.4 se le clasifique como
> "con" y si es menor igual sea "sin"

Primero que nada, si bien el enfoque mediante un ciclo explícito como ser `for` no está mal, en R hay formas más simples usando funciones que ya trabajan vectorialmente. Imaginemos estos datos:

```
set.seed(2023)
cosecha_quinto_mes_1 <- data.frame(
  site = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 30, replace = TRUE),
  year_class = sample(2021:2023, 30, replace = TRUE),
  diferencia_absoluta = runif(30, 0, 0.55)
)
```

En este caso, podemos usar `aggregate()` para agrupar y saber en cada grupo si hay algún valor superior a 0.4:

```
aggregate(diferencia_absoluta ~ site + year_class,
          cosecha_quinto_mes_1,
          FUN = function(x) {
            ifelse(any(x > 0.4), "Con", "Sin")
          }) -> grupos

grupos

  site year_class diferencia_absoluta
1    A       2021                TRUE
2    B       2021                TRUE
3    A       2022                TRUE
4    B       2022               FALSE
5    C       2022                TRUE
6    A       2023                TRUE
7    B       2023               FALSE
8    C       2023               FALSE
```

Con esto ya sabemos las combinaciones de `site` y `year_class` que cumplen la condición establecida, ahora si queremos que todas las observaciones de cada grupo hereden este valor, simplemente podemos hacer un `left join` con `merge()`:

```
merge(cosecha_quinto_mes_1,
      grupos, 
      by = c("site", "year_class")
      ) -> resultado

tail(resultado)
   site year_class diferencia_absoluta.x diferencia_absoluta.y
25    C       2022             0.4092251                   Con
26    C       2022             0.4724664                   Con
27    C       2022             0.5357507                   Con
28    C       2022             0.5437968                   Con
29    C       2023             0.3676134                   Sin
30    C       2023             0.3472329                   Sin
```